# Coping files from a folder listed in text file to somewhere

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains folder paths in separate lines; I want to copy all files from the path listed in the text file to a new folder. I am able to copy the files within a folder if I list the file name, but I am unable to copy the entire content of a folder listed in FromTo.txt to another folder.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Documents\From\FromTo.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Documents\To\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-Content "C:\Documents\From\FromTo | Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Documents\To\"
```

Comment: FromTo.txt is the text file which contains folder paths, i need to copy the files listed in the FromTo.txt file to the new folder